# How to read images from excel sheet(have multiple worksheets) using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, excel

I need to load .xlsx in node and angularjs app.

i have used some packages for that purpose like [js-xlsx](https://github.com/sheetjs/js-xlsx) it give me a all the data, but I can't find images of the excel sheets nor in JSON neither in HTML generated by js-xlsx package.

```
    var wb = XLSX.read(data.data, {
        type: "array"
    });
    let sheets = [];
    for (const key in wb.Sheets) {
        sheets.push({
            paneId: key.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase(),
            title: key,
            active: false,
            disabled: false,
            data: $scope.processData(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(wb.Sheets[key]))
        })
    }
```

I have also tried.

```
 XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(wb.Sheets[key])
 XLSX.utils.sheet_to_html(wb.Sheets[key])
```

**$scope.processData is the function for converting csv to array.**

Comment: if you just want the images, you may try to unzip it, the images will be in `excel.xlsx.zip/xl/media`

Comment: i want images along data, because i need to shoe whole file in HTML table.